# JavaFX WebView passing URL string to webEngine.load(url)

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

This is my first exposure to JavaFX2 and WebView. Every example I find contains an embedded url. Using a java app I am able to pass a url obtain from a MySql table and pass it to the web view application using the following code:

```
            public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    String wTripname = null;
    String[] wImage = new String[10];
    WebViewSample webView = new WebViewSample();
    MapSql mapsql = new MapSql();
    ResultSet rs = mapsql.performQuery("select trip_name, image_url " +
            "from mytracks.notations");
                    while (rs.next()){
            wTripname = rs.getString("trip_name");
            wImage[1] = rs.getString("image_url");
            int x = 1;
            String[] arg0;
            arg0 = wImage;          
            WebViewSample.main(arg0);
    }
        }
            }
```

I am able to pass the url as an arg to the main class in the WebView application in the following code:

```
    public class WebViewSample extends Application {
        private Scene scene;
        static String html = null;
        @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
           // create the scene
          stage.setTitle("Web View");
          scene = new Scene(new Browser(),750,500, Color.web("#666970"));
          stage.setScene(scene);
          scene.getStylesheets().add("webviewsample/BrowserToolbar.css");        
          stage.show();

          String htmlcontent = html;
          }

          public static void main(String[] arg0){
          html = arg0[1];
          launch(arg0);

          }
          }

          class Browser extends Region {
          final WebView browser = new WebView();
          final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();    

          public Browser() {
          //apply the styles
         getStyleClass().add("browser");
         // load the web page
         webEngine.load(html); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


        //add the web view to the scene
        getChildren().add(browser);

        }
        ....
```

I cannot pass the url html webEngine.load.

Surely there are methods to accomplish this but I can not find any sample code that helps.
I appreciate any help offered.

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: I have edited the question. The problem is passing an external url string to the WebEngine load method.

Comment: The html parameter of `webEngine.load(html)` is really an URL ? or an html document ? or an URL locating a non HTML document ?

Comment: what I want there is the url "html" which is the string passed as arg0 to the main class